# Disable or Re-Map Single-Purpose Keys on Lenovo Yoga 9i

Tags: autohotkey, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Yoga 9i which has single-purpose keys at the right-hand side of the keyboard:
[image]

These keys do things like change the power usage profile, sound settings, and toggle dark/light mode. I have tuned all of these settings the way I like them and don't want any of them changed, but I am always pressing these keys by accident when I'm reaching for Delete/Backspace/Enter. Whenever this happens I have to press them again a few times to loop through all possible options and get back to the settings I want (imagine accidentally pressing CapsLock, except there are more than 2 states to loop through). I would like to disable these keys or map them to things I would actually use, like Home, End, PgUp, and PgDn.

I tried AutoHotkey, but pressing these keys does not generate an event in its log :(

**Is there a way to disable or re-map these single-purpose keys?**

Comment: You can try [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) or [KeyTweak](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=KeyTweak#ip=1).

Comment: Make sure you got vendor software related to that installed first before checking AHK logs etc. E.g. https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-9-14itl5/downloads/ds551826-lenovo-fn-and-function-keys-for-windows-11-64-bit-yoga-9-14itl5?category=Mouse,%20Touchpad,%20Keyboard%20and%20Pen